# Get aspect ratio of viewport at draw time with grid

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I need to develop a new grid grob that is a customisation of segmentsGrob, but allows termination of the drawing at a specified length (i.e. cut 1 cm of the segment from the end). As the computations are a function of both the angle of the segment as well as the aspect ratio of the viewport (in absolute measures). The calculations needs to be pushed until drawing time using the drawDetails hook.

My question is how to get the absolute aspect ratio of the viewport in which the grob is being drawn? The context I'm using this in is ggplot2, and what I get if I query `current.viewport().width` or `current.viewport().width` is 1npc (thus not in absolute measures).

Example code

```
segmentsGrob2 <- function(x0 = unit(0, "npc"), y0 = unit(0, "npc"), x1 = unit(1, "npc"), y1 = unit(1, "npc"), startAdjust = unit(0, 'npc'), endAdjust = unit(0, 'npc'), default.units = "npc", arrow = NULL, name = NULL, gp = gpar(), vp = NULL) {
    if (!is.unit(x0)) 
        x0 <- unit(x0, default.units)
    if (!is.unit(x1)) 
        x1 <- unit(x1, default.units)
    if (!is.unit(y0)) 
        y0 <- unit(y0, default.units)
    if (!is.unit(y1)) 
        y1 <- unit(y1, default.units)
    grid.draw(grob(x0 = x0, y0 = y0, x1 = x1, y1 = y1, startAdjust=startAdjust, endAdjust=endAdjust, arrow = arrow, name=name, gp=gp, vp=vp, cl="segments2"))
}
drawDetails.segments2 <- function(x, ...) {
    asp <- getVpAspect() ### <-THIS IS WHAT I NEED

    # Do some modifications to x relative to asp

    grid:::drawDetails.segments(x, ...)
}
```